# Do we have DataSlice concept in AzureDataFactoryV2?

Tags: dataset, azure-data-factory, azure-search-.net-sdk

Like in AzureDataFactory we can use Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.DataSlice to get DataSlices from given Dataset. Do we have similar functionality in AzureDataFactoryV2 under Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory (Used for ADFV2) so that we can get previous DataSlices. I want to use ADFV2 .Net SDK to fetch DataSlices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADFv2 uses a different model than ADFv1.
The new model is based on triggers and not any more on a dataset slicing model as it was the case with ADFv1.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/compare-versions :

ADF v1

> Availability defines the processing window slicing model for the dataset (for example, hourly, daily, and so on).

ADF v2

> You do not need to define availability schedules for datasets. You can define a trigger resource that can schedule pipelines from a clock scheduler paradigm. For more information, see Triggers and Datasets.